# Setting parameters in a launch file does not appear to be working

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Some script which was working before, now does not work anymore. The issue is that the param instruction in the launch file, does not seem to have any effect in the executable file

```
<param name="camera_topic" value="/camera/image_rect"  type="str"/>
```

in my C++ executable, I looked for this "camera_topic" relative parameter as:

```
ros::param::get("camera_topic",camera_topic);
```

but I cannot get them easily. setting the same parameter in the program before getting it works, so I conclude it must be something about the launch file. The funny thing is that it worked before (+2 months).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43001/setting-parameters-in-a-launch-file-does-not-appear-to-be-working/) by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-04**:
I'm sure it still works in principle. You can check if and where it is set by rosparam list. If that doesn't help you need to come up with a complete minimal example.

**Comment by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on 2012-09-05**:
I have tried it thanks! I is there indeed. But the node executable somehow still does not read it. Could it be about time delay?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
Not if set by roslaunch. Test by launching the node manually, when the param is set - I suspect it won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't use a forward slash, "ros::param::get" gets a parameter from the node's namespace, but not its private namespace. If you put that parameter tag inside of a  tag, it will be in this private namespace.

For example, the following roslaunch xml:

```
<param name="camera_topic_root" value="/camera/image_rect">
<group ns="group_ns">
    <param name="camera_topic_ns" value="/camera/image_rect">
    <node name="node_name" pkg="foo" type="bar" >
        <param name="camera_topic_private" value="/camera/image_rect">
    </node>
</group>
```

Would set the parameters:

```
/camera_topic_root
/group_ns/camera_topic_ns
/group_ns/node_name/camera_topic_private
```

To get these parameters with the ros::param::get API, you could do each of the following:

```
ros::param::get("/camera_topic_root",camera_topic);    // /camera_topic_root
ros::param::get("camera_topic_ns",camera_topic);       // /group_ns/camera_topic_ns
ros::param::get("~camera_topic_private",camera_topic); // /group_ns/node_name/camera_topic_private
```

This is documented slightly less succinctly [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Accessing_Private_Parameters).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cduguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/1941/cduguet/) on 2012-09-11**:
Thank you! I missed the "~" in the private parameter! :). Basic question, I  hope this answer will help everyone making the same little mistake.